# SFMC - Query List ID and Push to Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

We have a "List" under All Subscribers and we want to move all of the contacts in that list to a Data Extension.  The reason for this is we want to have those individuals go into a Journey.

I wrote a query to do this and it works great with the parent account.  But when I'm in a child business unit, I get 0 records found.  Is there a way to do this?

This is the query from the parent account.  And the Parent account has its own list and DE that I tested it with.  But applying the same steps on a child BU results in no data being moved.

```
SELECT
EmailAddress,
[First Name] AS FirstName,
[Last Name] AS LastName
FROM [_ListSubscribers] LS
    INNER JOIN [_EnterpriseAttribute] EA ON ls.SubscriberID = EA._SubscriberID
WHERE ListID = 2416
```

Comment: in a child accounts, it needs to be ent._listsubscribers and ent._enterpriseattribute

Comment: Yes, I did try that as well.  It still returns 0 records...

SELECT
EmailAddress,
[First Name] AS FirstName,
[Last Name] AS LastName
FROM ent._ListSubscribers LS
    INNER JOIN ent._EnterpriseAttribute EA ON ls.SubscriberID = EA._SubscriberID
WHERE ListID = 2361

Comment: @niko any advice here :)